# Why Gaussian mixture model uses Expectation maximization instead of Gradient descent?

Tags: clustering, gradient-descent, gaussian, expectation-maximization, gmm

Why Gaussian mixture model uses Expectation maximization instead of Gradient descent?

What other models uses Expectation maximization to find best optimal parameters instead of using gradient descent?

Answer (score 1):

Not all the parameters (e.g., the assignment parameters) for a Gaussian mixture model are [smoothly differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness), thus can not be fit with gradient descent.

Other use cases for the expectation–maximization (EM) algorithm are:

- Clustering
- Latent variable estimation
- Missing data estimation

Comment: Thanks ,Could you please explain on what is meant by smoothly differentiable ? , i know that we have to find the best value for the mean vector ,covariance matrix  using Expectation maximization